# What is wrong with this To_Date() statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    INSERT INTO Log_Table 
    VALUES ('Mismatch', 'C:\Folder-SBX2\', '\Subfolder1\', 'm1.txt', 
        '37587b066cf68b3870101c4bbc1a5dc0', 'SBX2', '7.2 SP13 CC5', 
        To_Date('2013/04/04 11:46:06 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'));
```

Specifically that last line. I want the date to show up as **2013/04/04 11:46:06 AM** but instead it's entered as **04-APR-13**. What is the problem?

Comment: Where do you want it to show up? If it's SQL*Plus, you need to set the appropriate format with `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` before output. Try in SQL*Plus for example `alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'`, then perform your query.

Comment: when I do a select statement...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle stores dates in its own format.  Storage has nothing to do with display.

`04-APR-2013` is just the default format Oracle uses if we don't change it.  If you want to change how the date is displayed you need to change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in the client.  For instance, you could run this command:

```
sql>  alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM';
```

---

> "that is incredibly stupid. Not your answer, but Oracle I mean"

Umm, no.  What would be stupid would be storing dates in a variety of different formats. Check any of the myriad questions on SO from people who have dates stored as strings.

> " I use this alter session statement in conjunction with a Select statement to display the date properly"

You don't.  You have two choices.  The first - and in my opinion the better - option is to just return the date in the Oracle canonical format, and let the client software decide how to display it.  Alternatively you can use TO_CHAR and apply the format mask you want; only now you have cast the date to a string, and that may have undesirable consequences.

If you can persuade your DBA that your preferred format is the One True Format then they can change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT globally, so everybody will see dates rendered as you would like (unless they change their own local settings).

Comment: wow that is incredibly stupid. Not your answer, but Oracle I mean. How would I use this alter session statement in conjunction with a Select statement to display the date properly?

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't make sense that if you specify the format you want the date to be inserted as, then why wouldn't Oracle display it in the same format when you perform a select?

Comment: Oracle's data format doesn't have a mechanism for storing the input format.  It would double the size of the datatype.  Also what happens when you display dates entered by different users in different formats?  How ugly would that be?

Comment: @user1985189 And what would be your format proposal for `INSERT INTO foo (foo_date) VALUES (SYSDATE)`?

Comment: @APC hmm I see your point. I guess it would be too inefficient to specify the date format in the type when you are creating the table? I know that's not how it's done but that to me would make more sense

Comment: What about when we join two tables with dates in different formats?  Sorry but I remain unconvinced.  There are all sorts of things wrong with Oracle which are more urgent than this.

Comment: lol good points. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So add formatting to your select statement as:

```
select to_char(date_column, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
from my_table
```

Comment: I suppose this extra call costs you keystrokes and database performance.

Comment: No effort is too great in the service of our users.  More importantly, this changes the datatype of the output which places limitations on how the client software can interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot since I use Oracle, but as I see you are using a filter to indicate Oracle how to read the string as a date. If such, have you considered to match the slashes (left) and the minus (right) ?

Comment: hmm good catch. I tried changing the - to a / and it had no effect

Comment: I seem to recall this being a probelm back in Oracle v.6 (and perhaps 7).  These days Oracle is smart enough to swallow trvial differences in the separators.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
INSERT INTO Log_Table 
    VALUES ('Mismatch', 'C:\Folder-SBX2\', '\Subfolder1\', 'm1.txt', 
        '37587b066cf68b3870101c4bbc1a5dc0', 'SBX2', '7.2 SP13 CC5', 
        To_Date('2013-04-04 11:46:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'));
```

`HH` and `HH12` are equivalent.

Comment: yes I tried changing the - to a / and it made no difference. Why is Oracle so stupid?

Comment: The problem I guess is `AM`. You don't need to specify it since `HH` is 12 hours and will append AM or PM.

Comment: true, that worked when i omitted the am when the date is hardcoded as in this example. Problem is, I'm using  `DateTime.Now.ToString()` in ASP.NET to generate the date, which comes  with the AM and PM distinction. Sure, I could take a substring of that but then how can you tell whether a time is AM or PM when it isn't hardcoded in SQL??

Comment: It can be in the date parameter, just not in the format parameter. Have you tried `To_Date('2013/04/04 11:46:06 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')`